# Error using For loop

Tags: c++

I have problem running my loops.
I have to run a program where user enter 4 digit number, and it will show how many zero appear. This program will run depends on how many times user want it to run. so at the beginning I prompt user to enter the number of times the program will run, then the actual program will run in For loop. but so far, I can only run it once. Can someone help me? Thank you. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numberTimes;

    cout << "How many times do you want to run this check?\n";
    cin >> numberTimes;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < numberTimes; counter++);
    {
        int positiveInteger;

        //prompt user to enter a positive integer
        cout << "Please enter a positive integer value.\n";
        cin >> positiveInteger;


        //conditional statement
        while((positiveInteger <=0) || (positiveInteger > 9999))
        {
            cout << "Invalid Value!!! Please try again.\n";
            cout << "Please enter a positive integer value.\n";
            cin >> positiveInteger; 
        }

        cout << "Processing the value " << positiveInteger << ".\n";

        int zeroCount = 0;
        int firstNumber = positiveInteger%10; //separate the first number 
        if (firstNumber == 0) //determine if the first digit is zero
        {
            zeroCount = zeroCount + 1;
        }

        int digitOne = positiveInteger/10; //omitted first digit number
        int secondNumber = digitOne%10; //separate the second number
        if (secondNumber == 0) //determine if the second digit is zero
        {
            zeroCount = zeroCount + 1;
        }

        int digitTwo = digitOne/10; //omitted the second number
        int thirdNumber = digitTwo%10; //separate the third number
        if (thirdNumber == 0) //determine if the third digit is zero
        {
            zeroCount = zeroCount + 1;
        }

        int digitThree = digitTwo/10; //omitted the third number
        int fourthNumber = digitThree%10; //separate the fourth number
        if (fourthNumber == 0) //determine if the fourth digit is zero
        {
            zeroCount = zeroCount + 1;
        }

        cout << "Your first digit number is " << firstNumber << ".\n";
        cout << "Your second digit number is " << secondNumber << ".\n";
        cout << "Your third digit number is " << thirdNumber << ".\n";
        cout << "Your fourth digit number is " << fourthNumber << ".\n";

        cout << "Number of zero appear in your integer is " << zeroCount << ".\n";

        if (zeroCount % 2 == 0) //determine if the number is even or odd
        {
        cout << "Your number zero appear even times.\n";
        } else 
        {
            cout << "Your number zero appear odd times.\n";
        }
    }

    cout << "You have run this program " << numberTimes << ".\n";
    cout << "Thank you and good bye.";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Strip down your program to the bare minimum to show the problem.

Comment: nevermind, I find the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using `;` at the end of `for` line.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberTimes; counter++);
```

In such a case that you used, it iterate the loop but do nothing.

In the other word,it is equal to the below program now :

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberTimes; counter++)
   {
   }
```

You can also use this program : (Add complementary lines)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInteger;
    int numberTimes;
    int digit;

    cout << "How many times do you want to run this check?\n";
    cin >> numberTimes;

    while(numberTimes)
    {
        int zeroRepitation=0;

        cout << "Please enter a positive integer value.\n";
        cin >> positiveInteger;

        if ((positiveInteger <=0) || (positiveInteger > 9999))
        {
            cout << "Invalid Value!!! Try again!\n";
            continue;
        }

        for (int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            digit = positiveInteger % 10;
            if (digit=0)
                {
                ++zeroRepitation;
                }
            positiveInteger = positiveInteger / 10;
        }


        cout<<"Number of zeros in this number= "<<zeroRepitation;       
        --numberTimes;
    }
```

Comment: thank you. that is what I notice too. Anyway, is there any other way to write the code more efficiently?

Comment: @NumbNuts Yourwelcome.I added a program to the answer. As I don't have any `C compiler` installed, I may have some errors! :D

Comment: Thank you so much. that definitely looks more efficient and better

Answer (score 0):

You put a semicolon at the end of the `for` statement. This:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberTimes; counter++);
```

should be this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberTimes; counter++)
```